# Import SQLite database using Qt/QSqlDatabase

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have two separate applications, one placed at the production another at an office, and I need to get a **copy of** an **sqlite database** generated and updated at production side.

Until now I've tried two approches:

1. Copy the entire sqlite file from the production-application and "redirect" my QSqlDatabase-handles to that file (was not able to get it to work, many connections are already opened and not all closable)
2. Access the sqlite-db over network, query all data and insert the missing data using sql (works, but since there is a lot of data it takes too much time)

Are there possibilities to **import** or maybe **override** an existing database (or even single tables, placed in different files), where there are still open connections?

Using: Qt 4.8, SQLite, Windows 7, VS2010

Comment: Copy the file to your local temp dir, then use the backup API to replace the database.

Comment: File is already copied for backup reasons... Going to have a look at the backup api asap and leaving a feedback here! Thanks

Comment: @CL. works like a charm! Thanks for your tip. Add it as answer and I'll upvote and accept it :-)

Comment: You can answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I was able to reach my goal by using the sqlite backup api (which is distributed as .h and .c with most Qt versions). On the documentation page [SQLite Backup](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) there are a few examples, where a database is copied either from a file to an in-memory db, or from an in-memory to a file. In my case I used the following function (1:1 from doc page, only several comments removed):

```
int loadOrSaveDb(sqlite3 *pInMemory, const char *zFilename, int isSave){
  int rc;                   /* Function return code */
  sqlite3 *pFile;           /* Database connection opened on zFilename */
  sqlite3_backup *pBackup;  /* Backup object used to copy data */
  sqlite3 *pTo;             /* Database to copy to (pFile or pInMemory) */
  sqlite3 *pFrom;           /* Database to copy from (pFile or pInMemory) */

  /* Open the database file identified by zFilename. Exit early if this fails
  ** for any reason. */
  rc = sqlite3_open(zFilename, &pFile);
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){

    pFrom = (isSave ? pInMemory : pFile);
    pTo   = (isSave ? pFile     : pInMemory);

    pBackup = sqlite3_backup_init(pTo, "main", pFrom, "main");
    if( pBackup ){
      (void)sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);
      (void)sqlite3_backup_finish(pBackup);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_errcode(pTo);
  }

  (void)sqlite3_close(pFile);
  return rc;
}
```

The only additional steps to get the handle needed in the function above were:

1.Get sqlite-handle from QSqlDatabase

```
QVariant destVar = database.driver()->handle();
```

2.Check handle for validity and cast to sqlite3*

```
if(destVar.isValid() && qstrcmp(destVar.typeName(), "sqlite3*") == 0)
{
    sqlite3* destination = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(destVar.data());
    ...
}
```

Thanks to CL. (who was pointing the right direction).